# Group values from a text file in python

Tags: python, file, matrix, optimization

I have a text file, which contains 1s and 0s, where the 1s represent a pixel to be painted whereas the 0s denote an empty space. I have a painter function that prints the 1s - however, it runs a 160 commands to print the 1s (meaning there are a 160 1s in the file).

Here is an image of what the text file looks like:
[Image of Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlnIf.png)

This is what the final output should be with the least number of commands:[The solution score takes the MAX SCORE / NUMBER OF COMMANDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV2yj.png)

My solution function is as follows:

```
import threading
import time

def solution(imat, painter):
nrows, ncols = imat.shape #This gets the rows and cols of the file 
a = []
for r in range(nrows): #loops through every index in the file for rows
    for c in range(ncols): #loops through every index in the file for cols
              if imat[r][c] == 1: #checks where a 1 is in the file
                a.append(imat[r][c])
                painter.paint('square', r, c, 1)  #if it is a 1 then it paints that pixel.
```

My goal is to group the 1s from each row as one and then print it using the `painter.paint(...)` function as a block, thus reducing the number of commands it has to run, but I am unsure of how to do so. Therefore, instead of 160 commands, it runs commands equivalent to the number of rows or less.

Any advice and help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to optimize this problem how you would like. Right now, you have two loops, which result in `O(nm)` time.

To group the `1`'s in each row, you'll need to know the positional information of each cell, which again requires two loops. By grouping this you'll actually do **more** work, as you'll have to iterate the matrix to group the rows, and then iterate the rows to do the actual painting.

However, if you're deadset on getting all the positional information, you could make a dict with rows as keys, add column positions to a list:

```
import collections    

rows = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(range(nrows), [])

for r in range(nrows):
    for c in range(ncols): 
        if imat[r][c] == 1: 
            rows[r].append((r,c))
```

The result would look like (for a 2 row square of all ones):

```
rows = {
    0 = [(0,0),(0,1)],
    1 = [(1,0),(1,1)]
}
```

Which groups 1's by row, and holds the column position in a list.

`numpy.where` also does a similar thing, but returns all positions (not grouped by row), and also uses 2 nested loops in its implementation.

Comment: So basically, if I loop through the dictionary, and check if the value at the column position is 1 then it should print it?

Comment: No, the dict only holds the positions of the 1's. There would be no need to check.

Comment: I've also updated it to use `OrderedDict` so if you loop through the keys they'll return in the order `0..nrows`. Additionally, the values now hold the complete coordinate for easier access.

Comment: I see what you mean now, thanks so much, and one more question, the 'd[r] ' is a list, right?

Comment: That is correct, the second argument in `fromkeys` states the default value for each key-value pair (in this case it's `[]`).

Comment: I tried the d[r].append((r,c)) line, but I got an error saying list index our of range. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: This may be of help in understanding my problem. [This is the output that I need, where the solution score is the max score / number of commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV2yj.png)

Comment: That's because it should be `rows[r]`, not `d[r]` - my bad!

Comment: I'm sorry, there's one last thing that I would like to know - is it possible to print the whole row as one command?

Comment: You mean print all the coordinates of `1`'s in a row? Yes, just: `print(row[n])`, which will print a list of `(x,y)` tuples.

Comment: Basically if you take a look this image -> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV2yj.png) I want to print those blue blocks as one instead of a single iteration.

Comment: Does your paint command allow for handling more than one coordinate at a time? If not, how do you expect to print them all at once? You didn't provide this information in your initial question.

Comment: Yes it does allow for handling of more than one coordinate. I'm sorry, I didn't realise that I did not mention it - my apologies. Here is a link to the paint command: [Paint Command](https://gist.github.com/PrathamPatel/db928dd70b53189239b8e9cecd21d1b7)

Comment: I'm not going to decipher the entire file for you. If it handles more than one coordinate simply send it the lists from the `row` dict in my answer. I've also provided an example output so you can see how it's created.